# How to Connect My Django App with incoming data on a TCP Port

Tags: python, django, tcp

I am trying to connect a django URL to incoming data on TCP/IP Port.
It would be great if someone, could shed some light on this

Comment: It will be great, if you give more details on the question.

Comment: I basically want to listen to a specific tcp port say 10000 which will receive data from a device, and I want to push that data onto a django URL to make use in my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably have to listen on the port from another process, or thread.  Save the incoming data somewhere, whether it be a log file, database, or whatever.  Then have Django use this data when it prepares the web page to send in response to requests on the URL.

Comment: So basically , is it creating a TCO/IP Listener to save the incoming data and POST it to a Django URI ?

Comment: Oh, so you need to send it TO Django, and not FROM Django?  That's easier; I'd say you're right - a TCP/IP listener that POSTs stuff to the Django URL.  Django really doesn't enter into it, then.