# Printing Time spent on a view in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views, django-middleware

I have a simple **django** view which just reads the request and prints it out into the console. Now along with the request body I need to get the start time of the view for a particular session and if after the session has been terminated or there is **no request incoming for that particular view for about 1 min**, I need to print out a custom string `"Device Stopped"`.

Can anyone please help me out to solve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call)

Comment: Thank you. I have already tried it. But I need specific solution for django WSGI requests.

Comment: F.Y.I. My application is somewhat like this : [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212161/how-to-connect-my-django-app-with-incoming-data-on-a-tcp-port)

I just want to get the start and stop time of the tcp connection