# Measure Time spent on a view in django

Tags: python, django, templates, time, view

I have a django view that prompts the user to enter something into an input. I want to measure the time that the user took to submit the form. How is this possible?

I've seen related problems like [Printing Time spent on a view in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44137153/printing-time-spent-on-a-view-in-django) but it doesn't seem to solve my issue, because I do not want to measure the time taken on a function call.

Alex

Comment: i think the would be a good fit for the middlewares https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/middleware/#:~:text=Middleware%20is%20a%20framework%20of,for%20doing%20some%20specific%20function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pythons time package.

```
import time

# -user opens form-
start_time = time.time()
formExemple = input("Enter your age: ")
print("It took the user",  (time.time() - start_time), "secconds to submit the form.")
```